# sed to change the first match of a different match

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I want to change the `PATH` and `LOC_NAME` of specific group in a text file.

For example:

```
[a]
PATH=/tmp
SUR=Y
LOC_NAME=USA
[b]
PATH=/tmp
SUR=N
LOC_NAME=UK
```

So if for searching `[b]` I want to change the only the first match coming after it (after not after the next `[*]`):

```
sed -i '/PATH/c\PATH=\/u01'
sed -i '/LOC_NAME/c\LOC_NAME=RUS'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close!

You can add an *address range* for the part that should be changed. If you want to leave everything untouched outside the block from the `[b]` line to the next line starting with `[`, choose an address range with a comma between both expressions (now you got only the block to be changed), invert it with an `!` (now you got everything else) and use the command `b` to branch to the end of the script. So every command that follows will only affect lines inside the range:

```
sed -i '/^\[b\]$/,/^\[/!b
  /PATH/c\PATH=\/u01
  /LOC_NAME/c\LOC_NAME=RUS'
```

Of course, instead of inverting and branching you could use a `{commands;...;}` block for the uninverted match, but I think that's less readable.

If you want to use a word inside a variable as identifier, you can do like this:

```
ID=foo
sed -i '/^\['$ID'\]$/,/^\[/!b
  /PATH/c\PATH=\/u01
  /LOC_NAME/c\LOC_NAME=RUS'
```

Comment: If I change `b` to a word I get `char 23: extra characters after command`. How can I change it so it will work?

Comment: Works also fine with a word: `/^\[yourword\]$/,/^\[/!b`. Maybe you took the `b` command at the end of the first line for the identifier? Just replace the `b` in `\[b\]` with your word.

Comment: Yeah I meant both of them (after all this's the point). It doesn't accept not operator if this is a word.

Comment: The not operator is okay, but if you have a string like `good`, `sed` doesn't know what to do with `ood` following the `g` command, so you get the message `extra characters after command`

Comment: So what if I want `!` on a whole string?

Comment: The `!` inverts the whole match. You seem to want to use a variable, so I edited my answer: the variable needs to be expanded outside the single quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69796/discussion-between-nir-and-philippos).

Comment: The site chat is blocked here :( , anyway, yeah I use variable but you forgot the `[/!b` the two `b`s are the same. `[/!b` also should be something like `[/!$ID`

Comment: The chat worked for me, but anyhow that's what I tried to explain: Only the first `b` was for the identifier, the second `b` is the command `b`ranch, so don't touch it. I didn't forget it, it's correct like I wrote it.

Comment: You are corrent, although I didn't undestood why. I'll do a search on commands and ranch in regex. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier with `awk` or Perl:

```
$ cat input
[a]
PATH=/tmp
[b]
PATH=/tmp
OTHERPATH=/somedir
[c]
PATH=/tmp

$ gr="[b]"
$ repl=/u01
$ awk -vgr="$gr" -vrepl="$repl"  '/^\[.*\]$/ { group=$0 } group == gr && /^PATH=/ { $0 = "PATH=" repl } 1' input
[a]
PATH=/tmp
[b]
PATH=/u01
OTHERPATH=/somedir
[c]
PATH=/tmp

$ gr=b
$ repl=/u01
$ gr=$gr repl=$repl perl -pe '$group = $1 if /^\[(.*)\]$/; s,^PATH=.*,PATH=$ENV{repl}, if $group eq $ENV{gr}' < input
[same output]
```

The idea is to find lines that have `[something]`, take a note of the name there, and then make the replacement conditional on that. (Note that the awk version takes the group name with the brackets, the Perl version without them. The latter is prettier, but not as trivial in awk as in Perl. The Perl version takes the variables through the environment, so you'll need to `export` `gr` and `repl`, or assign them on the same command line.)

I modified that to replace only if the key is exactly `PATH`, but those will still change all `PATH`s under the same `[b]` heading (not just the first), but I'm not sure if you can have multiple.

Comment: Looks good. Can modify the answer so that the `b` and `/u01` values will be bash variable?

Comment: @Nir, yeah, `awk` makes that easy, I wish Perl had something similar, but the environment works as a workaround (see edit).

Comment: Both are correct but since my OS doesn't support `gawk -i inplace` I choose the other answer.